# 1 bar in wrong order in stacked bar chart (R ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I made a stacked bar chart, however the segments of the 3rd bar are in a different order; the segment that should be on the bottom is now on the top, see image:

[image: stacked bar chart]

When I change the order of the x axis, it does exactly the same with the 3rd bar. How can I solve this? Something wrong with the code?

```
library('ggplot2')
bar <- ggplot(data.location, aes(Location, value, fill=variable))
bar + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", position="stack")+labs(x="Location", y="value", fill="variable")
```

Added: output from dput(data.location)

```
dput(data.location[data.location$Location %in% c('BRM', 'CG', 'DDO'),])

structure(list(Location = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("BA", "BRM", "CG", "CH", 
"DDO", "DR", "FB", "GG", "GI", "GQS", "HC", "HS", "LL1", "LL2", 
"MOW", "PP", "TP", "TR", "TRD", "WB"), class = "factor"), Zone = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"
), class = "factor"), value = c(425.810194245673, 815.265455416096, 
735.274721619422, 997.041922511793, 2147.03610300279, 1210.08829970945, 
0, 177.692085889937, 173.266014794846, 406.498315338813, 1293.35105648741, 
234.022025228589)), .Names = c("Location", "Zone", "variable", 
"value"), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 42L, 43L, 
45L, 62L, 63L, 65L), class = "data.frame")​
```

Comment: can you add `dput(data.location)` of say the first three bars? `dput(data.location[data.location$Location %in% c('BRM','CG','DDO'), ])`

Comment: @rawr I added dput(data.location)

Comment: thanks! although with this data, your code works for me as you want. does @wyldsoul's solution work for you? I also notice that you don't have a legend in your picture, so what other code are you using to make that plot?

Comment: Yeah it works! Simply by using geom_bar instead of stat_summary.. strange but it works now so i'm happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code, I get consistent order of the bars.

```
ggplot(data.location,aes(Location,value,fill=variable,order=variable))+
geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]